# why i can't run use command python3 but it work on thonny python

Tags: pi-3b+, python-3

[image]

it work here

[image]

but it get erro when i use commend. this erro that i get

```
192.168.247.109 - - [15/Jul/2022 19:46:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in detectMultiScale, file /build/opencv-L65chJ/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp, line 1681
192.168.247.109 - - [15/Jul/2022 19:47:00] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 260, in execute
    for data in application_iter:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 870, in _next_
    return self._next()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 82, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
  File "/home/pi/Pi-Smart-Doorbell/main.py", line 44, in gen
    frame = camera.get_frame()
  File "/home/pi/Pi-Smart-Doorbell/camera.py", line 26, in get_frame
    obect_rects=haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
cv2.error: /build/opencv-L65chJ/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1681: error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale
```

pls help me?? :(

Comment: please post all text as text, not as screenshots

Comment: My guess is that Thoney sets the environment variables correctly and you don't have them correct in the shell.